# Why does this Makefile error out?

Tags: makefile, iteration

I'm making a `Makefile` to iterate over files and execute a command for each file. The commands execute fine but then `make` errors out. This is my `Makefile`:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

link: .gemrc .vimrc .gitconfig
    $(foreach df, $^, cat $(df) )
```

The output is the contents of each file and then `make: *** [link] Error 1`

How do I make `make` not error out?

Comment: You mean ignore the return value of the executed statement?

Comment: What can I do to discard the return value?

Comment: Prepend with `-` symbol to the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the command expands to `cat .gemrc cat .vimrc cat .gitconfig`, which gives an error because it can't find a file named `cat` to, well, cat.

Here are two of ways to do it:

```
link: .gemrc .vimrc .gitconfig
    cat $^

link: .gemrc .vimrc .gitconfig
    $(foreach df, $^, cat $(df);)
```